# Save Google apps script GUI form as an image

Tags: forms, user-interface, google-apps-script

Im am working with google apps acript on Goolge spreadsheet to create a simple tree object as a GUI.

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("A").setWidth('1000').setHeight('600');
  var tree = app.createTree().setAnimationEnabled(true);

   var item = app.createTreeItem("B");
   tree.addItem(item);

  var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setSize('980', '580').setStyleAttribute('border', '1px solid black');
  scrollPanel.add(tree);
  app.add(scrollPanel);

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}
```

I would like to save this GUI as an image (png, jpg, pdf...) so that I could be able to put it in a report.

I would also like to embed the GUI in the spreadsheet so that I could be able to print it.

Can anyone help me?

I know that this could appear as a strange request but what I am trying to do is to create a very special kind of graph using the GUI tree object, that has not a counterpart in the graph objects

Comment: Create a document with the [Document Serviçe](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) and place the items within this doc and after that if you want you can present it as a pdf. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969388/using-html-file-to-output-a-pdf) as well.