# Save web page as Google Doc (or PDF) to Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, save, drive

Is there a way to save a web page, to a Google Document, or a PDF in Drive?

Using:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob()).setName("fileName");
```

I have been able to get the HTML content, and save it in a file in Drive, but it will save a document containing the html code, not the intepreted web page render.

Is there any known way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in this question: [Using HTML file to output a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969388/using-html-file-to-output-a-pdf).

Following my own start, the code would be:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var htmlBody = response.getContentText();
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName('fileName.pdf');
DriveApp.createFile(blob);
```

Thanks, and apologies for the double question, it was really hard to find.