# How to convert multiple URLs to a series of individual PDF?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, url

I have an issue.
I have a file with a long list of URLs (hundreds of them) and I need to convert them into a series of individual PDFs of docx-files to be able to use them further with NVIVO.

After googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371162/convert-multiple-url-to-individual-pdfs/75587238) discussion that perfectly matched my issue. I tried to follow the instructions - created a Google Sheet, adopted a code to my case but it didn't work - instead I got a message "*Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp*". When debugging I got informed that the **document** is *undefined*. I am complete newbie in using Google App Script so I have no idea what exactly I did wrong. Could you please help me?

Here is the code I use:

```
function convertDocuments() {
  /* Select the Spreadsheet */
  const SS_ID = "1_4rjweZYHTTed6j740rVSZIFVPsrww6KvKwFikmlOzM"
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID)
  const PDF_MIME = "application/pdf"
  const newFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('PDFs')
  /* Get the links */
  const getLinks = SS.getRange('A1:A51').getValues()
  getLinks.forEach((cells)=>{
    const link = cells[0]
    if(link==="") return
    /* Getting the ID from the URL */
    const parseID = link.toString().split("/")[7]
    /* CREATE THE PDF */
    const document = DriveApp.getFileById(parseID).getAs(PDF_MIME).copyBlob()
    /* Inserting the PDF into the file */
    newFolder.createFile(document)
  })
  Logger.log(newFolder.getUrl())
  /* downloadFolder(newFolder.getId()) */
}
```

Here is the Google Sheet I tried to test it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_4rjweZYHTTed6j740rVSZIFVPsrww6KvKwFikmlOzM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: You need to re-assess your strategy. In [Convert multiple URL to individual PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71371162/1330560), the links were "Google Doc URLS", and `const parseID = link.toString().split("/")[7]` was extracting a document ID used in `getFileById`. In your case (and I'm speaking off the cuff), you would need to open each url, save the content to a new document, get the document ID and save as PDF. But the key is to retrieve the content of the URL in save it to a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save a list of external URLs as PDFs. A script based on converting a list of Doc URLS was inadvertently used as a basis for your script.

The answer below takes the substance of your script and adapts the method described in [Save web page as Google Doc (or PDF) to Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849630/1330560) to save each URL to a PDF.

This script could be made more efficient but as it stands it processes the 50 URLs in @100 seconds.

Note that there was one failure:

- `http://www.kremlin.ru/events/president/transcripts/articles/5413/photos/print` which return a 404 error.

---

```
function saveURLAsPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var links = data.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  //Logger.log(links) // DEBUG

  // Create a new folder
  var parentFolderId = "1wL9AyFsAgIjFruQSLfTmTX3uYEU7z9FV"
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  var pdfFolder = parentFolder.createFolder("PDFS");

  // create arrays to track errors, file url, and file name
  var errors = []
  var pdfURL = []
  var fileName = []

  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: i"+i+", url:"+links[i])
    var url = links[i]
    var parseID = url.toString().split("/")[7]
    //Logger.log(parseID)
    var pdfName = +(i+1)+"-"+parseID+".pdf"
    //Logger.log("i:"+i+", name: "+pdfName)

    try{
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var htmlBody = response.getContentText();
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);   
      var newFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blob);
      var fileURL= newFile.getUrl()
      errors.push(['OK'])
      pdfURL.push([fileURL])
      fileName.push([pdfName])
  }
  catch (error){
    errors.push(["failed"])
    pdfURL.push([" "])
    fileName.push([" "])
   }
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,2,links.length,1).setValues(errors)
  sheet.getRange(1,3,links.length,1).setValues(fileName)
  sheet.getRange(1,4,links.length,1).setValues(pdfURL)
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I didn't think that the code I tried to use was linked to the Google Docs - and it makes total sense. The line you indicated is initially corrupt - I somehow missed it when cleaning the test file. However, the new code doesn't work for me yet - it immediately states that "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheetByName')". It looks like there is some issue with the Active Spreadsheet (or maybe not).

Comment: OK, it finally works! I replaced SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() with SpreadsheetApp.openById("1_4rjweZYHTTed6j740rVSZIFVPsrww6KvKwFikmlOzM") and also manually created a new directory on my Google Drive and placed its ID into parentFolderId line. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Actually, I have one more question - not as crucial but anyway. It turns out that the IDs of the articles are pretty much random numbers and when the output pdfs are named just by the IDs, the original order of the article is getting lost. Is there any way to name pdfs not by their IDs but by sequential numbers (1, 2, 3...) or to put these numbers in front of IDs (1-67694, 2-66181, etc.) to keep the original order? Thanks!

Comment: No problems. Refer to script; I've added the file name and the file URL. Note: because "i" is zero-based, you need to "add one" to create a row reference for the File Name . The first file name (in row#1) will be `1-67694.pdf`.

Comment: "I replaced SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() with SpreadsheetApp.openById". That's interesting but I guess it depends on whether and how the project was bound. I should have said that my project was bound to the spreadsheet. Main thing is that you worked through that hiccup to get a successful outcome.

Comment: Thanks!! Your renewed code works but I have to add "'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);" at the end of line 30 - it looks like it has been accidentally deleted or something like that.

Comment: Aaaaand - I have one more question (the last one, I promise!). All output pdfs (no matter if I use basic URL or the one for a version "for print") include extended headers, printed menus etc., which make working with the files quite uncomfortable. However, if I just send webpage to print there are nothing of this kind - just plain text. Is there any way to make output files cleaned out of excessive information as if they were printed from browser? I tried to figure it out by myself but did not succeed. Thanks!!

Comment: "but I have to add"... whoops. Sorry about that, don't know what happened there. Glad you were able to resolve it.

Comment: "Aaaaand"... I think I understand what you mean but I don't have an answer (quick or otherwise) for that. There probably is a "simple" solution but I suggest that you post it as a new question and attract some attention from more knowledgeable users.